# Защита API на базе fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, авторизация, fastapi

Существует `Python`-сервер IoT-системы с API на базе `fastapi`. В процессе разработки вполне удобно то, что можно получить доступ к функциям API через обычный веб-браузер. Однако, этот API (в обычной эксплуатации) должен быть доступен только с использованием специального софтá, например, клиента IoT-системы для компьютера. Как это можно реализовать? Не хотелось бы, чтобы была возможность получить важную информацию, просто набрав ссылку в браузере.

Comment: Всегда можно написать браузерную имитацию этого "специального софта".

Comment: Если задача - скрыть секреты от посторонних, то нужно проводить аутентификацию отправителя, например по паролю или токену

Comment: Вам подходит моё решение?

Comment: @hedgehogues, да, подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Авторизация/аутентификация обычно реазилуется по токену, либо с помощью специальных сервисов Авторизация/аутентификация. В fastAPI сделана своя хорошая поддержка [Авторизация/аутентификация](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/http-basic-auth/).

Вы также можете использовать [middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/), с помощью которых сможете проверять токен доступа, либо же отправлять запросы на сервис Авторизация/аутентификация.

Один из примеров, Вы можете посмотреть, например, [здесь](https://github.com/U-Company/python-private-service-layout). После этого Вы получите сервис с готовой Авторизация/аутентификация в рамках [swagger](https://github.com/U-Company/python-private-service-layout/tree/master/%7B%7B%20cookiecutter.service%20%7D%7D#swagger).

Comment: Пожалуйста, представьте пример кода, который реализует авторизацию по токену в fastapi. В вашем объяснении недостаточно конкретики. Спасибо.